# Override styles in Fab button is not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react with material ui, and I added fab button, the component is:

```
     import React from "react";
import Styles from "./content-header.module.css";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
     
     const ContentHeaderTitle = ({ title, showIcon, handleOpen }) => {
       return (
         <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" mb={2}>
           <h4 className={Styles.title}>{title}</h4>
           {showIcon ? (
             <Fab
               size="medium"
               aria-label="add"
               onClick={handleOpen}
               className={Styles.fabBackground}
               color="inherit"
             >
               <AddIcon />
             </Fab>
           ) : null}
         </Box>
       );
     };
     
     export default ContentHeaderTitle;
```

I want to change the background and thats why I created a .module.css and I import how we saw in the last code. The css has:

```
.title {
  margin: 0;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.fabBackground {
  background-color: rgb(3, 135, 195);
  color: white;
}
```

The title style works, but the button not

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with  `classes` and trigger the root class already defined

```
<Fab
     size="medium"
     aria-label="add"
     onClick={handleOpen}
     classes={{ root: `${Styles.fabBackground}` }}
     color="inherit"
>
```